# Javascript multidimensional array length problem

Tags: javascript

JavaScript multidimensional array length always returning 0, how can I solve this problem?

[image]

```js
class test {

  static init() {
    test.arr = [];
  }

  static add() {
    let user_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    if (test.arr["u_" + user_id] === undefined) {
      test.arr["u_" + user_id] = [];
    }
    test.arr["u_" + user_id].push({
      "somedata": "here"
    });
  }

  static length() {
    return test.arr.length;
  }

}
test.init();
test.add();
test.add();
console.log(test.arr.length); //Always returning 0
```

Comment: is this javascript or typescript?

Comment: @hien as it is tagged js and includes no typescript specific code, I guess it is JS ?

Comment: [Don't abuse arrays when you need an object](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), or maybe a `Map`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5223/1048572)

Comment: @bergi https://jsfiddle.net/v9anhzc0/

Comment: @ÇağrıYıldırım See the edit on Jonas' answer.

Answer (score 1):

An array is a sorted set of *numeric* key value pairs. `"_u" + user_id` is not numeric, it's a string, therefore it gets stored as a regular property on the array (it behaves like an object) and not as part of the array itself. If you want to use a key-value storage with a length, use a `Map`.

```
 const test = { // no need for a class if you dont have instances
   arr: new Map(), // no need for that unneccessary init
   add() {
    let user_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    if(!this.arr.has("u_" + user_id)) { // I prefer "this" over "test", both work however
      this.arr.set("u_" + user_id, []);
    }
    this.arr.get("u_" + user_id).push({"somedata": "here"});
   },

   length() {
    return this.arr.size; //Note: it is "size" not "length" on a Map
   },
};
```

Sidenote: `arr` and `test` are very bad names.

Comment: same returning 0

Comment: @Çağrı Yıldırım whoops, must have been sleeping while answering, you have to use `.get` and `.set` on a `Map`

Comment: You even might want to drop the `"u_"` prefix and just use the `user_id` only as the key

Comment: @ÇağrıYıldırım Yes, that's still the same code (without using `.get()` and `.set()` methods) which doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

An array index can be defined as number only. If you want to get the length of an array, there are two ways to achieve this.

- You need to define the index as number instead of a string.
- Make a separate object, add your object (`{"somedata": "here"}`) into the object and push it into the array. Check the code below.

  ```
  let test=[]
  let obj = {}
  let user_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

  if(obj["u_" + user_id] === undefined) {
    obj["u_" + user_id] = [];
  }

  obj["u_" + user_id] = {"somedata": "here"};
  test.push(obj)
  ```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: How do I get the length?

Comment: You just need to console.log(test.length).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following jsbin I made you.
https://jsbin.com/xeqacuf/edit?console

```
    constructor()
    {
        console.log("new object created");
        this.test = { arr : {} };
    }
```

It's close to what you are trying to do...
Let me know if you need explanation or more help.
I'm willing to assist as much as youd like.
Notice that I changed the datatype from collection to objectKeyValue which allows you to query the object by key like you wanted.